# Transfer of steps and expected result from the development environment to the TestRail

Tags: java, testng, autotest, selenide, testrail

There are a lot of autotests on the project, JAVA + TESTNG + SELENIDE stack. Now we are moving to testrail, manual tests are being rewritten for the testrail format. Is it possible to pass steps and expected resilt from the development environment, either from the .xml test config, or from Java classes.
Suppose, when changing the autotest, it was enough to correct the steps and the expected result in the code(.xml or java class), and the data would be loaded into the testrail (steps and exp. result)

Answer (score 0):

**Post data to TestRail with Java**

You can use `testrail-api-java-client` for this task.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codepine.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>testrail-api-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You'll have to generate an API key in TestRail user settings and use it.

There are some examples in the readme:
https://github.com/codepine/testrail-api-java-client

**Integrate with TestNG**

To post results from testNG you have to implement and apply `TestNGListener` which will post the data in real-time, or generate some meta-report, which will be posted to testRail in some post-action.

Example:

```
public class TestRailPublishListener implements ITestListener {

  TestRail testRail

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    // post result to TestRail with testRail.. execute()
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    // post result to TestRail with testRail.. execute()
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    // post result to TestRail with testRail.. execute()
  }

...

}
```

**Reference between test steps int the code and TestRail scenario steps**

If you want to update your TestRail scenario steps when the code changed, it's a complicated task. I think you have to implement some logger which collects the test steps(and expected results) during execution. And after the test scenario is finished you have to delete old steps and preconditions and add the new ones recorded by the logger.

This is a very high-level description.

---

**TestRail API Reference**

In advance, instead of `testrail-api-java-client` you can implement your own TestRail client or use Java bindings provided by TestRail.

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/getting-started/binding-java/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a commercial product called [Railflow](https://railflow.io/). It provides a very powerful integration of TestNG (and many more testing frameworks) with TestRail.
See the docs for the details:
https://docs.railflow.io/docs/testing-frameworks/testng

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Railflow